# Как перехватить событие нажатия клавиатуры в консоли?

Tags: java, консоль, input

Суть проблемы: есть некая программа, которая опрашивает устройство, в зависимости от ответа выполняет некие действия.

Но нужно дать возможность самостоятельно выполнять ограниченное количество действий с помощью "горячих" кнопок, например, банально завершить выполнение программы при нажатии клавиши **х**.

```
...
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Devices d = new Devices();
        while(true) {
            if (!d.pollDevice()) { break; }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Если добавить Scanner либо InputStreamReade, программа останавливается и ждет нажатия.

Comment: Кажется, на мой [подобный вопрос][1] решение так и не было найдено...


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/59025/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: 2Rams666, уже после публикования своего вопроса наткнулся на Ваш, стало уныло ...

Comment: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/

вот тут есть по теме, это всё-таки привязано к ОС, но если у вас получится завести, то будет круто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы вам не читать пользовательский ввод в отдельном потоке?

```
public class Main implements Runnable {

    private static boolean isRunning = true;

    public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (isRunning) {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            if (i == 1) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Main()).start();
        while (isRunning) {
            System.out.println("Running...");
        }
    }
}
```

Такой код не будет приостанавливать выполнение основного потока для чтения данных.

**Обновление**

Тут ничего не сделаешь, кроссплатформенного способа заставить Java реагировать на нажатия клавиш в консоли нет. В unix-like ОС есть возможность перевести консоль из построчного в посимвольный режим ввода, но в консоли Windows такого не предусмотрено. Можно прикрутить нативный модуль, однако, это также убьет кроссплатформенность. Ещё можно переписать приложение на графический UI фреймворк вроде Swing, там есть возможность кроссплатформенного отслеживания нажатия клавиш, но скорее всего это не то, чего хотел автор вопроса.

Comment: Вы меня опередили буквально на пару минут, тоже самое сделал, но все-равно большое спасибо, а то я не могу пока еще сам себе отвечать, не хватает рипутации

Comment: Все равно это не будет работать, как описал в вопросе автор, поскольку данные с клавиатуры попадут в программу только после нажатия `Enter`.

Comment: Тут ничего не сделаешь, кроссплатформенного способа заставить Java реагировать на нажатия клавиш в консоли нет. В unix-like ОС есть возможность перевести консоль из построчного в посимвольный режим ввода, но в консоли Windows такого не предусмотрено. Можно прикрутить нативный модуль, однако, это также убьет кроссплатформенность. Ещё можно переписать приложение на графический UI фреймворк вроде Swing, там есть возможность кроссплатформенного отслеживания нажатия клавиш, но скорее всего это не то, чего хотел автор вопроса.

Comment: @avp, ничего страшного, будут нажимать enter, основной вопрос заключался, как  не ждать потока ввода, мы его успешно решили.

Comment: @Unknown, Вы уверены, что хотите отлаживать многопоточную программу?

Comment: @avp, я добавляю результат нажатия клавиши в очередь выполнения команд, проблем не может быть ИМХО